# How to generate pdf from a pdf content that already saved in the db

Tags: php, pdf, html2pdf

Since I dont want pdf to be stored in a folder instead PDF Out put need to be stored in db like below.

```
 PDF is created using html2pdf.class.php

 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 $html2pdf  = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en');
 $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
 $html2pdf->writeHTML($pdf_invoice_content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
 $pdfdata    = $html2pdf->Output('document.pdf', 'S');

 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

By fetching the data from db, I want to create pdf. So I did like this but the pdf did not open.

```
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 $file_size  = sizeof($pdfdata); // data fetch from db
 $file_name  = 'test1.pdf';

 header("Content-length: $file_size");
 header("Content-type: application/pdf");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
 echo $pdfdata;

 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Any one have a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
I have stored the pdf data in db as blob and show the pdf like below.

$pdfdata     = $pdf_invoice_content;
        $file_name   ='test1.pdf';

        if($pdfdata){
            header('Content-type: application/pdf;base64');
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
            echo $pdfdata;
        }
```

This is working for me.